# java.lang.ang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, struts2

I am getting this error while deploying my maven build struts2-spring-hibernate web application.Does anyone know which maven dependencies are required to resolve the issue below??

```
11:52:00.479 [main] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization
 failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
h name 'sampleSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/appli
cationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.l
ang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455) ~[spring-be
ans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) ~[spring-beans
-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) ~[spring-beans-3
.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEAS
E]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEA
SE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567) ~[spring-beans-3.1
.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
```

I'm using currently the dependencies mentioned below but still getting the error.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-CR1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtidy</artifactId>
            <version>r8-20060801</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
            <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
            <version>2.0b5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rolling back to hibernate 3, it appears the class you are looking for is not included in the Hibernate 4 library.  Something has a dependency on Hibernate 3.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7.ga</version>
    </dependency>
```

[After doing some further research, I learned that it is JTidy that has the dependency on Hibernate 3](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/jtidy/r8-21122004).

Comment: I removed jtidy....we are using hibernate4 and is there not a way to resolve the issue using hibernate4?

Comment: @user1945329 The only way to use JTidy and Hibernate4 is to find a version of JTidy which uses Hibernate 4.  A quick search revealed no such library.

Answer (score 0):

i had compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.1.9'

i replaced it with compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.3.2.GA'

in my build.gradle

this is gradle syntax, converting to maven isnt difficult , this solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

The artifact hibernate-tools version 4.0.0-CR1, which you've added as dependency, uses hibernate-commons-annotations 3.2.0-Final, which uses DTDEntityResolver. **You must change the version of hibernate-tools for 4.3.1.CR1** (notice the dot, not dash, before C), which uses hibernate-commons-annotations 4.0.4.Final, then you'll not have this error anymore.